# Cannot load /modules/mod_dav_svn.so into server

Tags: apache

I'm getting a wired error when loading Apache (Win 2016 STD, Apache/2.4.29 x86, OpenSSL/1.0.2n SVN/1.9.2)

i.e.

```
"Syntax error on line ... of .../conf/httpd.conf:
Cannot load ...modules/mod_dav_svn.so into server: (...) The specified module could not be found:"
```

The file is in the conf file properly: "LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so"
The file exists in the "modules" folder.

Although Apache reports a syntax error, it is not because other modules are loaded just fine with the same syntax.
Other file also has this problem: "**mod_authz_svn.so**".

Prerequisites are loaded before this module successfully (mod_dav.so, mod_dav_fs.so).

The best part: in my lab it is working just fine but in the customer's machine (same OS mentioned), something is not working properly.

I really need any help you can give me here...

Answer (score 0):

mod_dav_svn.so is from subversion server - so it does not come with apache and has to be added. If you have - then to problem might be that a visual c++ runtime of another version is required. To find out you could try a tool like [dependecy walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

When all missing dependencies are installed on the system your apache should start.